# ReactJS: How to maintain Index for Multiple ReadMore/ReadLess Buttons in Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array -

```
    var profiles = [
    {
        name: "Name1",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        name: "Name2",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        name: "Name3",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        name: "Name4",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    }
];
```

I want to truncate the description string. Only the first 25 characters should be visible along with the Read More button. When Read More is clicked the state should expand and should show the complete string and when Read Less is clicked the paragraph should collapse.

**The issue is** when I click on `Read More`, it triggers click for all the paragraphs in the loop, and all the paragraphs expand/collapse together instead of the one where ReadMore/ReadLess is clicked.

Below is my code

```
const ProfileGrid = (props) => {
    const [textRevealed, toggleText] = useState(false);
    const truncLength = 25;
    return (
        <>
          {props.profiles.map((profile,index) => (
              <p>{profile.name}</p>
              <p>{textRevealed ? profile.profile_description : 
                 profile.description.substring(0, truncLength)}...
                            <Button onClick={() =>  toggleText(!textRevealed)}>
                                 {textRevealed ? 'Read Less' : 'Read more'}
                            </Button>
                }</p>
        </>
   )

}
```

I am not sure how to exactly maintain the index so when Read More is clicked, only the one that is clicked will expand/collapse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the collapse as a independent statement by transform it to a ReactNode, code my be like so.

```
const truncLength = 25
const ProfileGridItem = ({ name, description = '' }) => {
  const [isCollapse, setIsCollapse] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>
        {description.substring(0, isCollapse ? truncLength : undefined)}...
        <Button onClick={() => setIsCollapse(isCollapse => !isCollapse)}>
          {isCollapse ? 'Read Less' : 'Read more'}
        </Button>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

const ProfileGrid = props => (
  <>
    {props.profiles.map((profile, index) => (
      <ProfileGridItem key={index} {...profile} />
    ))}
  </>
)
```

Comment: Your answer is good. I have the same idea but the OP's code takes me too much time to be able to reproduce in code snippet :(. anyway, +1

Comment: If you could further help me out with adding CSS animation. Basically, I want to add ease-in-out 300s animation when the text is toggled. It should not occupy space when hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using `Component's` power.

It means that you should **`break down` each item into the independent component accordingly.**

As a result, you can control the sate of each item easily.

```
const [isShow, setShowHide] = React.useState(false);
```

```js
const ProfileGrid = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.profiles.map((profile, _) => (
        <ProfileItem {...profile} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const ProfileItem = (props) => {
  const truncLength = 25;
  const [isShow, setShowHide] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
      <p>
        {" "}
        {isShow
          ? props.description
          : props.description.substring(0, truncLength)}{" "}
        ...
        <button onClick={() => setShowHide((previous) => !previous)}>
          {isShow ? "Read Less" : "Read more"}
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

var profiles = [
    {
        name: "Name1",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        name: "Name2",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        name: "Name3",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        name: "Name4",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    }
];
ReactDOM.render(<ProfileGrid profiles={profiles} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this does answer my question. Also, thanks for flagging about breaking it down and using it as individual components.

Comment: Don't forget to give me an upvote as well as mark my answer as resolved by clicking the tick to have the reader in the future, Cheers ^^! @Mshah